# IDE c# для слабого компьютера

Tags: c#

Всем привет!
У меня очень слабый компьютер, но я хочу начать прогать на c#. Кто может подсказать IDE весом до 10гб, и чтобы не лагало?

Видеокарта: geforce 9800 gt

процессор: intel core i3

Comment: А есть выбор? Вы можете поставить либо `Visual Studio`, либо `Rider`, все, больше вариантов нету. Всякие VS Code и другие "блокноты" это не IDE, а просто блокноты на стероидах (хотя вон в VS Code на днях плагин новый появился - `C# Dev Kit`, который превращает Code в аналог студии, и то со своими ограничениями). Короче, выбор между VS и Rider, а тут думаю выбор очевиден, ибо Rider платный. Если готовы платить, или искать ломанную, то Rider плохо работает с новыми фишками языка, а также плохо работает с UI элементами (особенно XAML), но он кстати будет пошустрее VS как по мне.

Comment: Спасибо, буду апгрейдить комп

Comment: .NET Freamework 4.8, Notepad++ и https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/docs/ - это чтобы начать. Ну а потом Visual Studio Community Edition.

Comment: Можно попробовать VS Code. Он довольно лёгкий и плагинов куча.